# Format multiple values in a label with different colors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgsexpression

I need to create complex labels for sites that contain multiple values in each. These values are colored depending on their value (ex. in range = green, out of range = red). I need to do this from an expression. Has QGIS implemented this feature yet?

Here's and image of what I'm trying to reproduce:

[image: what I'm trying to reproduce]

Comment: Label font colour can only be set per label. So you'd need to use rule-based labeling to create a single label per row and displace them accordingly.

Comment: @Erik Is there a way to have these grouped labels bounded by a bordered rectangle as in the example?

Comment: Probably by a ton of frickling, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of QGis I'm running, 3.16 supports html formatting of label text.

[image]

The code to support conditional formatting is a little unwieldy, but it works. Just mind your html closures. Here's an example label value expression.

```
if(attribute(get_feature(@layer_name, 'sampleno', minimum(sampleno)+2),'PH') > 5.9 AND attribute(get_feature(@layer_name, 'sampleno', minimum(sampleno)+2),'PH') < 8.6, '<p style="color:green">','<p style="color:red">')
```